# How can I display a Javascript variable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add some javascript to my HTML document. In my example I would like to display the square of 2 in text with HTML. The result should be calculated using a js script. For example, consider this:

In my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var square = 2*2
</script>
```

In my body:

```
<p>The square of 2 is <span id="square">.</span></p>
```

What do I have to add to make this work?

Comment: On the other hand it's ok to ask beginner questions, but on the other hand this is covered in literally almost every JavaScript tutorial there is.

Comment: @Juhana, first one is on the one hand :p joke aside, my opinion is that SO is not made for answering this kind of questions.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Reputation! Fresh reputation! Come get it while it's hot!

Comment: I typed up a page long answer that was 3 lines of code and 100 lines of explanation and then couldn't submit it because the question was closed :p

Comment: @meagar You can still post it to one of the duplicates.

Comment: Hahahah, I can't. The post-answer box is gone after refreshing the page and I'm not retyping it all. Might be possible to get my saved draft back but I'm not *that* interested in doing so.

Comment: Yay, I apparently got retaliation-downvoted for just commenting in this thread. That hasn't happened in a while, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `innerHtml` of the span to the value so it would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var square = 2*2;
  document.getElementById('square').innerHTML = square;
</script>
```

But you will want to move this script to after where the span is written as the page is rendered procedurally and the span doesn't exist yet in the head.  The other option is to wrap your code in a `document.onload` function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.onload(function() {
      var square = 2*2;
      document.getElementById('square').innerHTML = square;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this code will show the error as innerHTML is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML Document Object Model, for example,

```
function changeText(){
 var ans = 2*2;
document.getElementById("square").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

Then, attach this javascript to an event such as

```
<body onload="changeText()">
```